# Java: Friendlier way to get an instance of FontMetrics

Tags: java, java-2d, fontmetrics

Is there a friendlier way to get an instance of FontMetrics than

```
FontMetrics fm = Graphics.getFontMetrics(Font);
```

I hate this way because of the following example:

If you want to create in a game a menu and you want all the menuitems in the center of the screen you need fontmetrics. But, mostly, menuitems are clickable. So I create an array of `Rectangles` and all the rectangles fits around the items, so when the mouse is pressed, I can simply use

```
for (int i = 0; i < rects.length; i++)
if (rects[i].contains(mouseX, mouseY)) { ... }
```

But to create the rects I also need FontMetrics for their coordinates. So this mean that I have to construct all my rectangles in the paint-method of my menu.

So I want a way to get the FontMetrics so I can construct the Rectangles in a method called by the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The really correct answer is to use Toolkit.

```
Font font = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 14);
FontMetrics fm = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getFontMetrics(font);
```

Comment: No it is not. The useage of [Toolkit.getFontMetrics(Font font)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getFontMetrics(java.awt.Font)) has been deprecated since Java version 1.2. It has been replaced by the Font method getLineMetrics.

Comment: LineMetrics does not what I want... I've looked into it a hundred times. Can I use LineMetrics to get the width of a String?

Comment: Why is it deprecated?

Comment: I *think* because it's too accurate, and doesn't account for the pixelation process when actually rendering this Font to a rasterized display. To this day, I still think the deprecation is a mistake.

Answer (score 11):

For me the easiest way was to:

```
Font font = new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,12);
Canvas c = new Canvas();
FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(font);
```

Benefits:

1. If you call c.getGraphics() it will return null (thus there is no graphics object)
2. This (canvas) will also work in headless mode.

Now you can easily get height and width...

Comment: `Canvas::getFontMetrics` just calls `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getFontMetrics()`. So really you are just instantiating a ton of garbage.

Comment: How do you come to that conclusion? [Canvas.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/awt/Canvas.java) does not have an own implementation of `getFontMetrics` method. It inherits the one from [Component.java](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/awt/Component.java). And in there `sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(font);` method is called. If you check that class there is no Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() call at all...

Comment: Aha, interesting. Different implementation. I think I was looking at grepcode for Component.java: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/Component-source.html#2200 It's a web of "peer" stuff. But if the "peer" is not there, it goes to that same file line 782. I haven't explicitly checked whether or not on my system it actually has such a peer. But given that the canvas is headless, I expect to see no peer (as there is no connection to the OS/window manager). That was how I came to this conclusion.

Comment: Yes but you are referencing some really old code from 2007 (no mention of oracle yet which bought sun) So it was JDK 1.6 times I would guess. That version is long time EOL'ed. You have to at least consider JDK 1.8 or higher...

Answer (score 2):

Once the background component, i.e. whatever is behind your menu, has been rendered, it has a `Graphics` object that you can use to get the metrics for a given font, just once.

You certainly don't want to be doing this in the `paint` method, which should be as lightweight as possible. I'd hang this code on a listener that gets called when the component is first rendered. It can store the resulting FontMetrics object somewhere where you can later access it, either in a `paint` method for drawing those menu item boxes.

Rather than determining the measurements of your menu graphics at the last moment, i.e. when `paint`ing, it might be a good idea instead to create some components to represent your menu. You can place those components on the Glass Pane [more info here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) so they'll float above everything else, and you'll have the added bonus that those components are all capable of accepting mouse clicks and firing listener events on them, and since they only capture events on their own geometry you don't even have to figure out which part of menu was hit by the click, if at all.

Another advantage of using components here is that you may entirely get around the requirement for fiddling with font metrics. There are ready-made menu items, or you could just use `JLabels`, and you can specify their alignment, you can use a `LayoutManager` to size the boxes to the width of the biggest label, and so forth.

Comment: There is no reason why `Graphics`/`Component.getFontMetrics` can't be passed down through a non-`java.awt.Component` component hierarchy.

Comment: Absolutely! And I'm not disputing that. I just pointed out that there is a school of "do all your graphics by computing and drawing" and one of "throw some components on your GUI and let them compute themselves." Both approaches have merits.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the menu text is fixed, you could pre-draw the text to a [BufferedImage](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) with alpha transparency and make your calculations then. Then, when you need the menu text, just draw the image.

You'll still have to do some offset calculations to centre the image (assuming the panel size can change), but these should be relatively lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good solution

```
private static HashMap<Font, FontMetrics> fontmetrics = new HashMap<Font, FontMetrics>();


public static FontMetrics getFontMetrics(Font font)
{
    if (fontmetrics.containsKey(font))
    {
        return fontmetrics.get(font);
    }
    FontMetrics fm = createFontMetrics(font);
    fontmetrics.put(font, fm);
    return fm;
}

private static FontMetrics createFontMetrics(Font font)
{
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
    Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
    g.dispose();
    bi = null;
    return fm;
}
```

Comment: A static map is wrong for so many reasons. (Although a decade ago I did use it for a performance hack.)

Comment: This worked for me on server-side code.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Lonzak said, how about this:

```
public static FontMetrics getFontMetrics(Font font){
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    GraphicsConfiguration config = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();

    Canvas c = new Canvas(config);
    return c.getFontMetrics(font);
}
```

You could store the 'config' variable as a static variable so it is constructed once in some utility font class that contains other font related information for your game/development environment. I guess you could also do this with the canvas variable.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense when I need this on server side code generating an image.

Answer (score 0):

Updated recommendation. `FontMetrics` is deprecated.  Use `LineMetrics` instead.

```
String text = "some string";
FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(font.getTransform(), true, true);
LineMetrics lm = font.getLineMetrics(text, frc);
```

However, some methods such as `SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth` require a `FontMetrics` instance.  Another option is to compute the bounds of the String.

```
Rectangle2D bounds = font.getStringBounds(text, frc);
```

Then the width and height may be obtained from the bounds.