# Repaint() FontMetrics

Tags: java, swing, fonts, paintcomponent, fontmetrics

I have something I need to draw on the screen, but that requires font metrics to draw correctly. I also need to use repaint() or something else to draw to the screen right then and there.

If I have a `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, I can retrieve the font metrics correctly via `g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont())`. The problem is, I cannot tell it to paint it's self. It only does it when something happens such as the component being resized.

Then if I use just normal `paint(Graphics)`, I may use `repaint()` to draw when I want it to, but calling `g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont())` does not return correct values. Any ideas?

```
repaint();//I need to call repaint() or something similar to draw to the screen when I want it to

public void paint(Graphics g){
    FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());//Returns different metrics than that of paintComponent(Graphics)
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());//Returns different metrics than that of paint(Graphics)
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to paint? Something like a rectangle  with text in it ?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753514/java-friendlier-way-to-get-an-instance-of-fontmetrics help?

Comment: also i would store Font as a variable within your class, and not override pain()

Comment: I figured it out, apparently `paint()` doesn't give the correct Font for g.getFont() so when I set the font, I set it to the variable and use that font object instead of using g.getFont()

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is, I cannot tell it to paint it's self.

You just use `repaint()` on the component. The repaint() method will invoke paint() which in turn invokes paintComponent(). See [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

> I set it to the variable and use that font object instead of using g.getFont()

From the tutorial link given above you will see that you should be overriding paintComponent() not paint(), so this is not an issue.